# Is it possible to derive the total (aggregate) Income of a region from the deciles of single individuals incomes and total population?

Tags: descriptive-statistics

I would need to derive the total (aggregate) Income of a certain region (to then compute the average). I have data on:

- disposable income for each individual of the region, but in deciles:

  1st decile: \$ 18.000

  2nd decile: \$ 21.000

  ...

  ...

  9th decile: \$ 54.000
- total population of the region: 119.312 individuals

From these pieces of information, is it possible to compute the total (aggregate) income of the region?

Comment: In general no. For example, the income of the top 10% is completely undetermined except as more than $54K. In these circumstances the total is not available. Your deciles might possibly hint at a distribution that fits roughly, but it's all the way uphill on which assumptions to make. The problem is on all fours with I make \$10000 a year and my friend makes more. How much do we make in total?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the total cannot be recovered, but with some additional assumptions it could be estimated. For example, if you are willing to assume (guess) on some parametric model, its parameters could be estimated. You could see your sample as interval-censored and try maximum likelihood estimation for interval-censored data, for instance.